# Why code is not executing if condition in my cypress code?

Tags: javascript, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to pass multiple condition in single if but code is ignoring it.

```
cy.get("locator").each($el) => {
if($el.hasClass("flatpiker-day ") && $el.text() == day)
   {
   //some code
   return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: because `$el.hasClass(".flatpiker-day ") && $el.text == day` is false? (traditionally, you don't look for classes starting with `.` in class functions)  plus your code is syntactically incorrect, what error is in your browser developer tools console

Comment: It is difficult to determine the exact issue without seeing your full code

Here are some potential solutions

Use triple equals (===) instead of double equals (==), Use .contains() instead of .text

Comment: use console.log to see the values of your variables

Comment: @JaromandaX - actually I have to click on calendar date in date picker and it is having two 30's ....My code is selecting 1st one which is 30th May 22 but I have to select 30th June 22...For this I am checking in this way if($el.hasClass("flatpiker-day ") && $el.text == day)

Comment: the code in the question is not the same ... also ... the code in teh question won't ever run because it's not valid syntax

Comment: @JaromandaX - sorry my mistake - if($el.hasClass("flatpiker-day ") && $el.text() == day)

Comment: Right, see how that's NOT the code that isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

If this is the HTML of the calendar

```html
<div class="dayContainer">
<span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="September 25, 2022" tabindex="- 1">25</span> 
<span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="September 26, 2022" tabindex="- 1">26</span>
<span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="September 27, 2022" tabindex="- 1">27</span> 
<span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="September 28, 2022" tabindex="- 1">28</span> 
<span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="September 29, 2022" tabindex="- 1">29</span> 
<span class="flatpickr-day prevMonthDay" aria-label="September 30, 2022" tabindex="- 1">30</span> 
  ...
```

then you can avoid double-up of `day === 30` by using the `aria-label`, which has the full date in it's value.

```js
cy.get('div.dayContainer')
  .find('span[aria-label="October 30, 2022"]')
  .click()
```

In general, **aria attributes** often provide a good way to select an element - see [testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#priority) for a full discussion.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `$el.hasClass('flatpiker-day')` could be `.find('.'flatpiker-day')` and the condition `$el.text() == day` could be `.contains(day)`, so a good test would be

```js
cy.get('locator')
  .contains('.flatpiker-day', day)
  .then($el => ... one element received here
```

But please note, if you are testing a calendar, the display can sometimes show the `day` twice.

You would have to give detail of the DOM to resolve that.